Can a damaged LCD cable cause a power surge that breaks a PCH chip in a laptop?
My laptop's screen stopped working but otherwise was functioning fine when attached to a separate screen.
I took it to a laptop place thinking it'll be an easy fix.
They told me that the LCD cable had micro damage, only visible under a microscope, and that this causes a power surge that broke the PCH chip.
Is this even possible or did they break my laptop through negligence?
If so, how do I prove it?

What is a PCH chip?

@Hearth Platform Control Hub (PCH) is a family of Intel's single chip chipsets that combine the northbridge and southbridge into a single chip.

They certainly could have broken it, but there's no way to prove it. It's also possible it's not broken at all and they are lying. An LCD cable suffering from a micro crack destroying the driver seems.. unlikely to me but not impossible. I don't think this question is answerable from the information provided (or likely to be able to be provided). It's the same thing that happens when you bring your car in for repairs- many mechanics will blame some unlikely 2nd order effect for their own negligence. Like the idiot that set off the airbags in an SUV I brought in for a friend.

Lucky he (the mechanic) kept his head attached when it went off. But his boss claimed the module was defective.

Yes it is definitely possible that what they say is that a cable between display and body of the laptop was damaged in such a way that it blew up the PCH chip. For example if it was a ground wire.
Your laptop was already broken in some way before they tried to find the fault and fix it.
You cannot prove at which point the PCH blew up, before sending it to repairs or after it.
If the PCH did blew up at the repairs, they also cannot know or prove if PCH was already blown or blew up when they performed troubleshooting.
They can simply state after troubleshooting what the situation is now that it is known.
